# How do I set a limit to max number of selections in multi select menu in Material UI react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multipleselection

I have a multi select menu from material UI component and I need to make sure that users can only choose three options from that menu as I need to send that value as props. Now, what should I do to ensure that? Here is the code that I am using:

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 2, width: "100%" }}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-chip-label">Location</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-multiple-chip-label"
      id="demo-multiple-chip"
      multiple
      value={selectedLocations}
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<OutlinedInput label="Location" />}
      
      renderValue={(selected) => (
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}>
          {selected.map((value) => (
            <Chip key={value} label={value} />
          ))}
        </Box>
      )}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
      {locationList.map((location: string,index: number) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={index}
          value={location}
          style={getStyles(location, selectedLocations, theme2)}
        >
          {location}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

The options that I am going to select are getting stored in `selectedLocations`. Now, what should I do to make sure that **a user can not choose more than three options**.

I was unable to find any info on this anywhere, including MUI documentation.

Expected Results: Only choose three options from the dropdown list

[Link to how the dropdown looks in general](https://codesandbox.io/s/f5vns7?file=/src/Demo.tsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an API provided in [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/) or [Select.MenuProps](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu/) for limiting the maximum number of selected options.

However, this can be achieved by disabling the options that are not selected whenever the maximum number of selected options is reached:

```js
{locationList.map((location: string, index: number) => (
  <MenuItem
    key={index}
    value={location}
    disabled={selectedLocations.length >= 3 && !selectedLocations.includes(location)}
  >
    {location}
  </MenuItem>
))}
```

[Live Demo](https://playcode.io/1642748)